# bigquery left join by closest previous value

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

I have two table as below:

TABLE_1:

```
timestamp                id
2020-11-24 01:05:00 UTC  AA
2020-11-24 01:07:00 UTC  AA
2020-11-24 01:07:00 UTC  BB
```

TABLE_2:

```
timestamp                id   covered
2020-11-24 01:04:00 UTC  AA   true
2020-11-24 01:06:00 UTC  AA   false
```

I want to add a column to table_1 to show covered value from table_2. Although timestamps are not matching, I want to get the closest previous timestamp captured in table_2.
For example AA was covered at 1:04 and uncovered at 1:06 so result table look like this:

```
timestamp                id   covered
2020-11-24 01:05:00 UTC  AA   true
2020-11-24 01:07:00 UTC  AA   false
2020-11-24 01:07:00 UTC  BB   null
```

Would you please help me to finish this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_1.timestamp, TABLE_1.id, TABLE_2.covered 
FROM TABLE_1 
LEFT JOIN 
TABLE_2
ON TABLE_1.id = TABLE_2.id
AND ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery is not thrilled with non-equijoins.  So an alternative is to use `union all` and some trickery:

```
select t12.*
from (select t12.*,
             last_value(covered ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as imputed_covered
      from ((select timestamp, id, null as covered
             from table_1
            ) union all
            (select timestamp, id, covered
             from table_2
            )
           ) t12
     ) t12
where covered is null;
```

This is combining the two tables.  The `last_value()` is then retrieving the most recent `covered` value -- which for `table_1` rows will come from `table_2`.

The final `where` just filters the result set to only have `table_1` rows.